# Abstract repositories specific api under data model, and querying it using linq

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns

at moment i'm working with few third party repository; these repositories allow me to access to datas only through some specific apis.

What i would to understand is if there is a pattern, that i should use, to abstract each api of each repository for mapping them under an unified datamodel; so that i can query datas using linq, regardless about  underlying repository.

Ps :
I'm not interested in all crud operation i would only read queries results, i have no need to edit data (in any way).

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your needs are a bit contradictory.

> What i would to understand is if there is a pattern, that i should
>   use, to abstract each api of each repository for mapping them under an
>   unified datamodel;

Yes, take a look at `Adapter`, `Facade` and `Bridge` in a less degree (all of them are described in GoF). More general it relates to some unified contract (your Repositrory) and model translation. In such case I recommend to look at `Anti-Corruption Level` pattern from DDD, and also other DDD patterns related to model translation.

The point I confused with is

> so that i can query datas using linq, regardless about underlying
>   repository.

Repository semantic is in **hiding of technical details**, thus you are working with Repository abstraction like In-memory collection. Actually, relying on ability of all `Repository` implementations to correctly translate and efficiently use your linq-like queries is a bit naive. Moreover it can be a sufficient limitation for separate (independent) evolution of your App and third-party-repositories.

Finally, as you are working with interface as with a public contract, **all implicit technical or implementation logic assumptions (about how something is implementend in nutshell) lead to tight coupling** with all consequences. But, if you still want to use LINQ, you can create wrappers for third-party repositories and implement your own LINQ-to-YourRepoTechs provider, but I think it's not worth to be done.

If your third-party repositories provide also technical-specific API, I would recommend to create autonomy service (Web) wrappers for them for 1) encapsulating of technical API difference, 2) translating model with respect to your needs. And to forget about LINQ.

It will be more robust and flexible.